# SQL Query to get table names by foreign key dependency

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

How could I frame a query to get table names in SQL Server by order of Foreign Key dependency?

If there is a Table XYZ, which is the Primary table on which 2 other tables have a Foreign Key constraint, then I would want the Table XYZ to appear first.

This is to enable the creation of tables in the correct order.

Comment: It's easier to create tables without foreign keys and then alter them afterwards as you don't get this problem. Also the general problem isn't solvable, as you can have circular dependencies (though that's usually bad design)

Comment: As a side note, using SQL Server Projects in VS2010 will do that automagically for you.

Answer (score 0):

This query will return tables in their dependency order:

```
     ;WITH vwTableDependancy AS (
        SELECT 
            tables.object_id Dependant , NULL Parent
        FROM 
            sys.tables
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            sys.foreign_keys
        ON
            foreign_keys.parent_object_id = tables.object_id
        WHERE
            foreign_keys.parent_object_id IS NULL
        UNION    
        SELECT 
            parent_object_id Dependant, referenced_object_id Parent
        FROM 
            sys.foreign_keys
    )
    , vwTableHierarchy AS (
        SELECT Dependant,Parent, 0 lvl FROM vwTableDependancy WHERE Parent IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            vwTableDependancy.Dependant,vwTableDependancy.Parent , lvl+1
        FROM 
            vwTableDependancy 
        INNER JOIN
            vwTableHierarchy
        ON
            vwTableDependancy.Parent = vwTableHierarchy.Dependant
    )
    SELECT 
         OBJECT_NAME(Dependant) Dependant
        ,OBJECT_NAME(Parent) Parent
        , lvl  
    FROM 
        vwTableHierarchy
    ORDER BY 
        lvl ASC
    OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: I know this is a bit old now, but as @Laurence pointed out, circular dependencies will break this. With `MAXRECUSRION` set to `0`, if you have a circular dependency then this query will run until you get a system out of memory exception. You can add an exclusion to the CTE to reject any record where `parent_object_id = referenced_object_id` which would work (demonstrated in [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d029/1)).

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from sys.tables st
join sys.foreign_keys sfk on st.object_id = sfk.parent_object_id 
where sfk.name = 'Foreign_Key'
```

Answer (score -2):

You can find the information you want in the following tables :

```
select * from sys.tables
select * from sys.foreign_keys
select * from sys.foreign_key_columns
```

From there, build the script that will do just as you need.